# lofiadm: password via script

Tags: solaris

I have a server running OmniOS and on top of that napp-it to manage ZFS. Every now and then I need to send data to the ZFS file systems. I do this using a bash script and rsync.

Following the [instructions of napp-it](http://www.napp-it.org/extensions/encryption.html), I created a bunch of encrypted block devices with lofiadm. Whenever I want to open the block devices I need to enter the password for each device twice. With at least 6 block devices this is cumbersome. Looking at the [manual of lofiadm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36871/lofiadm-1m.html) I can not find an option to send a password in plaintext.

Is there some way some way around so that I do not have to enter the password manually? As my main hard drive is encrypted I do not mind storing the password in plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [source code](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/lofiadm/main.c#864), `lofiadm` uses [`pkcs11_get_pass`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libcryptoutil/common/passutils.c#64) from `libcryptoutil.so` to get the password:

```
864 rv = C_OpenSession(cipher->slot, CKF_SERIAL_SESSION, NULL, NULL, &sess);
865 if (rv != CKR_OK)
866     goto cleanup;
867
868 /* get user passphrase with 8 byte minimum */
869 if (pkcs11_get_pass(NULL, &pass, &passlen, MIN_PASSLEN, B_TRUE) < 0) {
870     die(gettext("passphrases do not match\n"));
871 }
872
873 /*
874  * salt should not be NULL, or else pkcs11_PasswdToKey() will
875  * complain about CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID; the following is
876  * to make up for not having a salt until a proper one is used
877  */
878 salt = pass;
879 saltlen = passlen;
880
881 klen = cipher->max_keysize;
882 rv = pkcs11_PasswdToKey(sess, pass, passlen, salt, saltlen, ktype,
883     cipher->max_keysize, &kvalue, &klen);
```

And `pkcs11_get_pass` uses [`getpassphrase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/getpass-3c.html#scrolltoc):

```
72  if (token_name != NULL)
73      (void) snprintf(prompt, sizeof (prompt), DEFAULT_TOKEN_PROMPT,
74          token_name);
75  else
76      (void) snprintf(prompt, sizeof (prompt), DEFAULT_USER_PROMPT);
77
78  for (tries = MAX_PASS_TRIES; tries > 0; tries--) {
79      tmpbuf = getpassphrase(prompt);
80      if (tmpbuf == NULL)
81          return (-1);
82
83      if (strnlen(tmpbuf, min_psize) >= min_psize)
84          break;
85
86      if (token_name != NULL)
87          (void) printf(DEFAULT_TOKEN_MINSIZE, min_psize);
88      else
89          (void) printf(DEFAULT_USER_MINSIZE, min_psize);
90  }
91  if (tries == 0) {
92      (void) printf(gettext("Exceeded number of attempts.\n"));
93      return (-1);
94  }
```

The [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/getpass-3c.html#scrolltoc) for `getpassphrase()` says it won't work without access to the terminal:

> The getpass() function opens the process's controlling terminal,
>   writes to that device the null-terminated string prompt, disables
>   echoing, reads a string of characters up to the next newline character
>   or EOF, restores the terminal state and closes the terminal.
>
> The getpassphrase() function is identical to getpass(), except that it
>   reads and returns a string of up to 257 characters in length.
>
> ...
>
> **ENXIO**
>
> The process does not have a controlling terminal.

So it appears there's no easy way to script password entry.